# Simplification of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Can anyone help me in an intuitive manner how to simplify the following conditional probabilities and expectations - $E(Y|X)|X$ and $E(E(Y|X)|X)$ -? I am trying to use their literal interpretation (the expectation of $Y$ conditional on $X$ conditinalized on $X$) to see how to move forward, but that has failed me so far. any tips welcome.

Comment: @User1885516 - please see derivation on https://files.nyu.edu/cds2083/public/docs/methods/lie_notes.pdf

Answer (score 3):

First, the entity $E(Y|X)|X$ does not exist (and the phrase "the expectation of $Y$ conditional on $X$ conditinalized on $X$" is pure mumbo-jumbo).

Second, $E(E(Y|X)|X) = E(Y|X)$ by definition, because the random variable $E(Y|X)$ is $σ(X)$-measurable and because $E(Z|X) = Z$ for every $σ(X)$-measurable (integrable) random variable $Z$.

Comment: apologies - on the first question - i misread the line - the original line stated E(E(Y−E(Y|X)|X)), and hence i made a mistakes with regards to the brackets. that said - can you expand more what σ(X)-measurable implies (or send a link)? unfortunately - my knowledge falls short here

Comment: This is all over the place, really. Williams' book *Probability with martingales*, Rosenthal's probability books, anywhere... Which book are you following yourself?

Comment: And my answer implies that `E(E(Y−E(Y|X)|X))=0`, and even that `E(Y−E(Y|X)|X)=0 a.s.`, do you see this?